# R Programming- Used customising package ggfortifty on plot

Tags: r, graph, time-series

Hi I created a time series in R and used GGfortify to make it look pretty.

It uses a function called autoplot for which I wish to change the axis and title names, but I am unsure how to.

```
salesARMAplot <-arima(sales, order = c(1,1,1))
FinalForecast <-forecast(sales, x=banter, y= banter,ARMAplot,h=8)
autoplot(FinalForecast)
```

The image attached shows the plot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following parameters inside the autoplot function

```
xlab = "x_label", 
main = "title", 
ylab = "y_label"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add to it like a normal ggplot object:

```
autoplot(FinalForecast) + ggtitle("Forecast Title") + labs(x = "New Time")
```